# Way to iterate through object to create array of objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that I want to use the keys as keys in a new object and the value into a child object. How could I go from A to Z?

```
const a = {key1: 'text', key2: 'text2'}

const z = [{ key1: { similarTo: 'text' } }, {key2: {similarTo: 'test2'}}]
```

Comment: I meant how to get const a to look like const z

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to achieve it:

```js
const a = {key1: 'text', key2: 'text2'};
const z = Object.entries(a).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: { similarTo: v } }));

console.log(z);
```

Comment: I like this, but find `... .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: { similarTo: v } }))` easier to understand

Comment: Is there also a way I could add a switch statement in there to check what the key so that I could change the similarTo to something else?

Comment: @ScottSauyet - I agree and therefore edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @bananapancakes3 - You can switch inside the map clause if you really want to.